# Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth Programming with Python

Tags: bluetooth

I have successfully connected my cell phone to the Raspberry Pi's onboard Bluetooth. I know the Bluetooth works, but I cannot get connection on Bluetooth to work properly.

I get this error when I run the script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Desktop/bluetest.py", line 34, in <module>
>       s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))   File "", line 5, in connect BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')

How do I fix this, or what do I need to do to make this work?

```
import bluetooth
from bluetooth import *

serverMACAddress = '00:13:EF:C0:02:1E'
port = 3
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
while 1:
     text = raw_input() # Note change to the old (Python 2) raw_input
     if text == "quit":
         break
     s.send(text)
sock.close()
```